# CasperJS won't click on table of dates

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, click, casperjs

```
<td>
    Search Downloadable Full Charts by Date:
    <br>
    <select name="raceDate">
        <option value="20150821">August 21</option>
        <option value'"20150822">August 22</option>
        ...these options continue until yesterday(the default)
        ...
        <option selected="" value="20151004">October 4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" onclick="setSearch('D');" value="Search">
```

With RSelenium this works:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath',
                             "/html/body/div/div[4]/div[1]/center/
                             table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/input")
webElem$clickElement()
```

but with casperjs I get the error message that the xpath is non-existent, even if I use css selectors:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.clickLabel('.interior-content.col-sm-8>center>table>tbody>tr>td>form>table>tbody>tr>td>input');
});
casper.then(function(){ 
    console.log('clicked search default search ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
});
```

```
dave@dbox:~$ casperjs --version
1.1.0-beta3

dave@dbox:~$ phantomjs --version
1.9.2
```

Linux dbox 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4 (2015-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

I've also tried many other examples from stack as well as the CasperJS docs.

Comment: <td>
 Search Downloadable Full Charts by Date:
 <br>
 <select name="raceDate">
  <option value="20150821">August 21</option>
  <option value'"20150822">August 22</option>
  ...these options continue until yesterday(the default)
  ...
  <option selected="" value="20151004">October 4</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" onclick="setSearch('D');" value="Search">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.interior-content.col-sm-8>center>table>tbody>tr>td>form>table>tbody>tr>td>input` is a CSS selector and not a label (element text). You need to use `casper.click(selector)` instead of `casper.clickLabel(text)`:

```
this.click(".interior-content.col-sm-8>center>table>tbody>tr>td>form>table>tbody>tr>td>input");
```